# Updating data element in one JSON blob with data from another linked by ID

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON blob:

```
 {
"kind": "objects",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "IEAAW355KQE3LPMD",
        "accountId": "IEAAW355",
        "status": "Active",
        "importance": "Normal"
    },
    {
        "id": "IEAAW355KQE3LPME",
        "accountId": "IEAAW355"
        "status": "Active",
        "importance": "Normal"
    },
    {
        "id": "IEAAW355KQE3LPMG",
        "accountId": "IEAAW355",
        "status": "Active",
        "importance": "Normal"
    },
            {
        "id": "IEAAW355KQE3LBYH",
        "accountId": "IEAAW355",
        "status": "Active",
        "importance": "Normal"
    }
]
```

}

And I want to update JUST the "importance" data element in the first blob from the data in this second blob, linked on ID

```
  {
    "kind": "objects",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "IEAAW355KQE3COXZ",
            "accountId": "IEAAW355",
            "status": "Active",
            "importance": "Fast"
        },
        {
            "id": "IEAAW355KQE3LPME",
            "accountId": "IEAAW355"
            "status": "Active",
            "importance": "Slow"
        },
        {
            "id": "IEAAW355KQE3COPB",
            "accountId": "IEAAW355",
            "status": "Active",
            "importance": "Normal"
        },
                {
            "id": "IEAAW355KQE3LBYH",
            "accountId": "IEAAW355",
            "status": "Active",
            "importance": "Slow"
        }
    ]
}
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? I'm guessing something N squared potential would be the wrong way to go! Both these blobs can be variable lengths too... Just wondering what the fastest and most efficient way would be.

Comment: Whatever the method is...i think you cant "escape" from the loop...you can either use for-of loop or reguler for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
mergeData(src, dest, "id", "importance");

function mergeData(src, dest, uniqueKey, key) {
    return dest.map(d => {
        const filter = src.filter(item => item[uniqueKey] === d[uniqueKey]);
        if (filter.length > 0)
            return Object.assign({}, d, {
                [key]: filter[0][key]
            }); 

        return d;
    });
}
```